# Ajax - doesn't change URLs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework2

I made the contents of the page change using Ajax, but the problem is the site url stays the same, therefore it doesn't load the page at all, just the text on it. So for example, I click on the Login link and the content changes, but the url stays on site/, not site/login. The actual login form does not load because it doesn't even call it, only loads basic text. How can I fix that ?
P.S. Using Zend for the website
Script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(toLoad);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: That is the nature of AJAX. What did you expect to have happen? Also why is this tagged for PHP?

Comment: if you want the url to change, then you'll have to do window.location or whatever, forcing the browser to fetch the new url...

Comment: @Twisty I expected the content of the URL to load, without rerendering the layout

Comment: So you just want the text that would result from loading the link? What are you getting back currently? Could make a function to strip the markup off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ajax does not reload the page or load another page so the url does not change when you make an ajax request.

If you want the url to change, for example so that your ajax-filled pages can be shared and bookmarked, you need to change the url manually.

You can use the html5 history API for that.

A simple example:

```
// we need the click event here
$('a').click(function(e) {
    // cancel default click action using `e`
    e.preventDefault();

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load(toLoad);

    // check if the html5 history api is available in the browser first
    if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
      // push the state to the url in the address bar
      history.pushState({}, e.target.textContent, e.target.href);
    }

});
```

Now the url in the address bar should change to the url of the link but the link is not really followed, instead the ajax request was made.

Note that you also need to make sure that all your urls load correctly. This is just a simple example and by the look of it your linked url would not load a complete page.

Check for example the [documentation on mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history) for more information.